# conda list error in windows 7 64 bit

Tags: python, conda

When I activate the virtual environment to use conda and I write "conda list" from the terminal to see all the packages that I have installed I received the following message:

```
[pandas_env] C:\Users\michele.dellamea\Desktop\boms_sent>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\michele.dellamea\AppData\Local\Continuum\A
naconda3\envs\pandas_env:
#
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\michele.dellamea\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\pandas_
env\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(pip.main())
AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'main'
An unexpected error has occurred, please consider sending the
following traceback to the conda GitHub issue tracker at:

    https://github.com/conda/conda/issues

Include the output of the command 'conda info' in your report.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\michele.dellamea\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts\cond
a-script.py", line 4, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\michele.dellamea\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-pac
kages\conda\cli\main.py", line 173, in main
    args_func(args, p)
  File "C:\Users\michele.dellamea\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-pac
kages\conda\cli\main.py", line 180, in args_func
    args.func(args, p)
  File "C:\Users\michele.dellamea\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-pac
kages\conda\cli\main_list.py", line 254, in execute
    json=args.json, show_channel_urls=args.show_channel_urls)
  File "C:\Users\michele.dellamea\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-pac
kages\conda\cli\main_list.py", line 185, in print_packages
    add_pip_installed(prefix, installed, json=json)
  File "C:\Users\michele.dellamea\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-pac
kages\conda\pip.py", line 108, in add_pip_installed
    for pip_pkg in installed(prefix, output=output):
  File "C:\Users\michele.dellamea\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-pac
kages\conda\pip.py", line 49, in installed
    args = pip_args(prefix)
  File "C:\Users\michele.dellamea\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-pac
kages\conda\pip.py", line 28, in pip_args
    pip_version = subprocess.check_output(ret + ['-V']).decode('utf-8').split()[
1]
  File "C:\Users\michele.dellamea\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\subproce
ss.py", line 629, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Users\michele.dellamea\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\subproce
ss.py", line 711, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Users\\michele.dellamea\\AppData\\
Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\envs\\pandas_env\\python.exe', 'C:\\Users\\michele.
dellamea\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\envs\\pandas_env\\Scripts\\pip-s
cript.py', '-V']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

That when I write "conda info":

```
[pandas_env] C:\Users\michele.dellamea>conda info
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Current conda install:

             platform : win-64
        conda version : 3.19.3
  conda-build version : 1.19.0
       python version : 3.5.1.final.0
     requests version : 2.9.1
     root environment : C:\Users\michele.dellamea\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anacon
da3  (writable)
  default environment : C:\Users\michele.dellamea\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anacon
da3\envs\pandas_env
     envs directories : C:\Users\michele.dellamea\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anacon
da3\envs
        package cache : C:\Users\michele.dellamea\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anacon
da3\pkgs
         channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
          config file : None
    is foreign system : False
```

The strange thing is that i remember that one months ago the command "conda list" worked successfully but know it looks like that the things are changed.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem, and the solution is simple, just change your install directory to C:\Anaconda3, or some folder that doesn't contain dots or special characters and spaces.

Example:

```
C:\Anaconda3
C:\Users\Anaconda3
```

Please note that installing Anaconda in some directory different of your own (Your user folder) requieres to grant administrator privilegies.

After I reallocated Anaconda3 to C:\Anaconda3 all works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8156 .
Attempt was to remove C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\Sphinx-1.3.1-py3.4.egg\EGG-INFO file